# Clicking the button that is picture

Tags: .net, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I need help with my code. I am making program that will login to a site, then rate something (Bot), so on login there is no button, but picture and i used this:

```
For Each logn As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    If logn.OuterHtml.Contains("/images/login_button.png") Then
        logn.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
Next
```

to login...

But there is another button and i have no idea how to click it... 
Its picture like the first button, but i can't click it with same function... Site is http://www.toneaday.com
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call 'onclick'. See if this works.

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = logn.GetType().GetMethod("onclick");
mi.Invoke(logn, new object[0]);
```

(it's c#, you'll need to convert it to vb.net)

Comment: @Igor whats the error you are getting? Can you see if its submitting the form on via onclick?

Comment: I can't translate it properly... I must use translator, since i don't know C#. Also that is another button, not same one, so its bit different, i am not sure if i can explain it really well for you guys...

Comment: Calling onclick has no effect if the onclick property is not set.

Answer (score 0):

If the web site accepts a keyboard submit (pressing enter on a text input on the form), you should be able to simulate that by calling the form element's submit mathod, or if there is a onsubmit event handler, by raising the onsubmit event on the form. I think that's how WatiN handles image buttons.